# upload image to servlet: IllegalArgumentException !UFT8 error

Tags: servlets, base64, cocos2d-x

I want to upload an image from IOS device to Google datastore. 
This is how I did it:

1. On client side, I use cocos2d to get image raw data. **image->getData()**, which returns an (unsigned char*) type. I guess it's in base64.
2. I set, **std::string postdata = "image=" + (char *)(image->getData());**.
3. I use cocos2d HttpClient to send the postdata to a servlet.
4. On the servlet, I use **request.getParameter("image");** to get the image data. But I got an java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: !utf8 ERROR!

However, if I just set postdata = "image=XXXX", the servlet is able to return me "XXXX", which is what I want. So I guess the problem is:

"image=" is in UTF8, but image data is in base64.

Then servlet does not know how to decode the string and returns me !UTF8 error.

I don't know if my understanding is correct?

All I want is to let servlet receive **image data** and send it back to client.
Is any one know how to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Regards

Comment: don't transcribe your code, post it in full (as much as needed for context but not just the whole class)

Comment: Your question is pretty much answerable in general but given the information you provided we can not do that. Give us the code you used to get image bytes, how you set up HTTP request, how you deal with the request in servlet's `doPost` and, optionally, to you receive HTTP response. With this information we will be able to give you the necessary hints.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I solved the problem. It's just I need to encode the image data to base64, then post it to the servlet. Thanks any way.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. It's just I need to encode the image data to base64, then post it to the servlet. Thanks any way.